# ¿Cómo puedo guardar cambios temporalmente en git?

Tags: git

Usando ***Git*** para el control de versiones, estoy trabajando en un código en una computadora que debo dejar en un momento dado, quedando la tarea inacabada. Debo recuperar este código en su estado actual en otra computadora para continuar el trabajo. Como el código en desarrollo tiene que pasar por el repositorio remoto para ser "trasplantado" a la segunda máquina me planteo 3 posibles opciones:

1. Crear un commit que luego recuperare y al que añadir finalmente el código finalizado (amend).
2. Crear una nueva rama para guardar esos cambios que pueda ser eliminada finalmente.
3. Usar 'git stash'

No sé cuál método sea el adecuado por las implicaciones que puedan tener ya que necesito enviar los cambios al repo remoto para recuperarlos después. Es un repositorio privado en el que sólo trabajo yo y que está alojado en *bitbucket*.

Comment: lo mejor seria crear una rama, por que con stash solo guardaras los cambios en un borrador localmente asi que descartamos git stash.

Comment: El problema puede depender un poco de la propia estrcutura del proyecto, si añadir una rama va a ser muy lioso, aunque creo que que puedes incluso combinar tus opciones 2 y 3, ya que se pueden incluso crear ramas desde un punto creado con el stash. Esta web explica su uso: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Las-herramientas-de-Git-Guardado-rápido-provisional Espero te sea de ayuda. Salud

Answer (score 1):

La opción correcta es crear una rama de trabajo para esos cambios, hacer commit de los cambios, hacer push de la rama y luego el pull para descargar los cambios en la otra computadora. Luego, si querés, podés eliminar dicha rama.

Comment: Eso estoy haciendo, sí.